# Data from the default shipping address in customer grid

Tags: magento2, admin, customer, grid, indexer

Magento OOTB is displaying data from default billing address in customer grid. I need data from default shipping address instead of billing. I made changes in **indexer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Indexer/etc/indexer.xsd">
    <indexer id="customer_grid" view_id="customer_dummy" class="Magento\Framework\Indexer\Action\Entity" primary="customer">
        <fieldset name="shipping" source="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Address\Collection">
            <reference fieldset="customer" from="entity_id" to="default_shipping"/>
            <field name="full" xsi:type="searchable" dataType="text" handler="ShippingAddressHandler"/>
            <field name="street" xsi:type="searchable" dataType="varchar"/>
            <field name="firstname" xsi:type="searchable" dataType="varchar"/>
            <field name="lastname" xsi:type="searchable" dataType="varchar"/>
            <field name="city" xsi:type="searchable" dataType="varchar"/>
            <field name="company" xsi:type="searchable" dataType="varchar"/>
            <field name="region" xsi:type="searchable" dataType="varchar"/>
            <field name="telephone" xsi:type="searchable" dataType="varchar"/>
        </fieldset>
    </indexer>
</config>
```

I run:

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

and got this error:

```
 Customer Grid indexer process unknown error:
 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1070
 Too many key parts specified; max 16 parts allowed, query was:
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer_grid_flat`
```

How can I solve this? Maybe if I do not use billing data how can I remove it from indexer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can easily change with the just small change for shipping address,

```
<fieldset name="billing" source="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Address\Collection"
          provider="Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\Address\AttributeProvider">
    <reference fieldset="customer" from="entity_id" to="default_shipping"/>
</fieldset>
```

Here you need to change the value `to="default_shipping"` from `"default_billing"`

And make your module depends on `Magento_Customer` , clear cache